# Change text on parent div on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My idea is that i have something that looks like this in HTML

```
<h1> A title </h1>

<h2> Under title <h2>
<ul>
<li> something </li>
<li> something else </li>
<li> something third </li>
```

I wish to do so that when i hover over "something" - there is a hover effect on that item itself, AND the text in "A Title" changes to something else like "This title" ?? and the same for the other list items.

How would you go about this?? I have been searching for various hover states both in CSS and JS.. I am guessing now that it would have to be some kind of JavaScript.

Comment: Search for tooltip JS

Comment: Can the tooltip as simple as `<li title="my tip">`?

Answer (score 1):

Working demo:

```js
$('ul').on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    $('h1').text('This title');
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $('h1').text('A title');
  }
});
```

```css
li:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1> A title </h1>


<h2> Under title
  <h2>
    <ul>
      <li> something </li>
      <li> something else </li>
      <li> something third </li>
    </ul>
```

---

**For the hover effect on the** `<li>`

```
li:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

**For the title change :**

```
$('ul').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $('h1').text('This title');
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $('h1').text('A title');
    }
});
```

Comment: This does what I want! thanks! However, say if you wanted the h1 to change to something third when you hover over the "something else" and something fourth when you hover on the something third, what do I need to add to your code for that to work??

Comment: Then, instead of setting the handler on the `ul` element which wraps the whole list, you will set different handlers, on the different `li` elements. You can select the first li with `$('li:eq(0)')`, the second with `$('li:eq(1)')` and so on.

Comment: Technically you could also set only one handler on the `ul`, and analyze in the handler function which element is the 'source' of the event, assuming you add the argument `event` to the handler. That's a good thing to know if you have to deal with a lot of handlers, but I suggest you doing with what you are more comfortable with.

Comment: awesome! thanks for your help! Got it to work just as I wanted ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use the onHover HTML attribute and point it to a Javascript method or code.

HTML:

```
<h1 id="title" onHover="changeText()>A title</h1>
```

Javascript:

```
function changeText(){
    document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = 'You are hovering!';
}
```

Comment: Nope, the OP want an effect on `h1` when something else is hovered.

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged with jQuery so lets go with that with a little css. I've also use the [HTML Data Attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) to store the title text.

```js
var initTitle = $("#target").html();
$("ul li").hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $("#target").html($(this).data("title")).addClass("active");
  },
  function() {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
    $("#target").html(initTitle).removeClass("active");
  }
);
```

```css
/*Change what you want to in here for your hilite effect*/

.active {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="target"> A title </h1>

<h2> Under title <h2>
<ul>
<li data-title="First Title"> something </li>
<li data-title="Second Title"> something else </li>
<li data-title="Third Title"> something third </li>
<ul>
```